# remove multiple classes with a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code adds a class (a border in this case) to an single element (a square) when the user clicks on that element. This part of the code is working fine.

I would then like to be able to remove however many borders were added (1-3 in this example), with the click of a single button, using a for loop.

I was able to do remove the borders by just repeating item1.classList.remove('.bigBorder'); (for example with item1) but that certainly does not scale well.

```js
const item = document.querySelector('.item');

const item1 = document.querySelector('.item1');
const item2 = document.querySelector('.item2');
const item3 = document.querySelector('.item3');

const clearBordersButton = document.querySelector('.clearBorders');

const bigBorder = document.querySelector('.bigBorder');

item1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  item1.classList.add('bigBorder');
});

item2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  item2.classList.add('bigBorder');
});

item3.addEventListener('click', function() {
  item3.classList.add('bigBorder');
});

clearBordersButton.addEventListener('click', clearBorders);

function clearBorders() {
  for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    item[i].classList.remove('bigBorder');
  }
};
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.bigBorder {
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="item item1">item</div>
    <div class="item item2">item</div>
    <div class="item item3">item</div>
  </div>
  <button class="clearBorders">clear borders</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of attaching a listener to each `item` you can use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) - attach one listener to the parent component (`.boxes`) and have that listen to events as they "bubble up" the DOM from its children.

If you also select all the `item` elements with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) it's a simple process to iterate over them and remove the class.

```js
// Cache the elements
const boxes = document.querySelector('.boxes');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
const clear = document.querySelector('.clear');

// Add listeners to the container, and the button
boxes.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
clear.addEventListener('click', clearBorders, false);

// Because we're using event delegation
// check that the child element that was clicked
// on was has a `.item` class, and then add the new class
function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.item')) {
    e.target.classList.add('bigBorder');
  }
}

function clearBorders() {
  items.forEach(item => {
    item.classList.remove('bigBorder');
  });
};
```

```css
.boxes{display:flex;justify-content:space-around;width:250px}
.item{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;background-color:#efefef;border:10px solid white;margin:20px 0;width:50px;height:50px}
 .item:hover{cursor:pointer;background-color:#cdcdcd;}
.bigBorder{border:10px solid #000}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
<button class="clear">clear borders</button>
```

Comment: Always love a good example of event delegation, damn it, should have used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that `querySelector` returns the first matching element where as `querySelectorAll` returns a node list of matching elements.

We can use the node list to assign the event lister and remove the class.

```js
//Selects multimple itmes
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
//selects first matching itme
const clearBordersButton = document.querySelector('.clearBorders');

const bigBorder = document.querySelector('.bigBorder');

//Iterate the items
items.forEach(function(element){  
  //add an event listern
  element.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //"this" is the item clicked
    this.classList.add("bigBorder");
  })
})


clearBordersButton.addEventListener('click', clearBorders);

function clearBorders() {
  //find the elements
  document.querySelectorAll(".item.bigBorder").forEach(function(element){
    //remove the class
    element.classList.remove("bigBorder");
  })
  
};
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.bigBorder {
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="boxes">
      <div class="item item1">item</div>
      <div class="item item2">item</div>
      <div class="item item3">item</div>
    </div>
    <button class="clearBorders">clear borders</button>
  </div>
</div>
```